# not showing path -Google Static Maps API: Generating a static map with paths

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, url, path, static

I am using Labview to generate a URL for a static google map. In creating some points on it, I try to connect these points by path. The [generated URL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=26.518716,80.232393&zoom=5&size=650x450&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:orange%7Clabel:A%7CSize:small%7C26.516703,80.232561&markers=color:orange%7Clabel:B%7CSize:small%7C26.518716,80.232393&markers=color:orange%7Clabel:C%7CSize:small%7C28.704100,77.102500&path=color:0x0000ff80|weight:5|80.232561,26.516703|77.102500,28.704100) is not showing the path.

How can I show the path between the points?

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates are backwards in the "path":

```
path=color:0x0000ff80|weight:5|80.232561,26.516703|77.102500,28.704100
```

should be:

```
path=color:0x0000ff80|weight:5|26.516703,80.232561|28.704100,77.102500
```

[working URL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=26.518716,80.232393&zoom=5&size=650x450&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:orange%7Clabel:A%7CSize:small%7C26.516703,80.232561&markers=color:orange%7Clabel:B%7CSize:small%7C26.518716,80.232393&markers=color:orange%7Clabel:C%7CSize:small%7C28.704100,77.102500&path=color:0x0000ff80|weight:5|26.516703,80.232561|28.704100,77.102500)

[image: static map]

Comment: If this answered your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)